# How to detach from xpra, started from client?

Tags: xpra

I ran `xterm` as [in example](https://xpra.org/trac/wiki/Usage):

```
xpra start ssh/SERVERUSERNAME@SERVERHOSTNAME --start-child=xterm
```

And it worked. Now how to detach from it, to keep it running? If I ctrl-c the running program, it also kills `xterm` and doesn't allow to attach to in anymore.

It was told it is like `screen` but for graphics.

Answer (score 2):

There are three main ways to detach from a running `xpra` session started in this manner:

- from another shell, run

  ```
  xpra detach ssh/SERVERUSERNAME@SERVERHOSTNAME
  ```
- from the Xpra menu, click on “Disconnect”:

  [image: Xpra menu]
- kill the client `xpra` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> — in my experience this doesn’t kill the remote `xterm`, it detaches it.

The remote session can be resumed with

```
xpra attach ssh/SERVERUSERNAME@SERVERHOSTNAME
```

If you have multiple `xpra` sessions running, specify the display number too:

```
xpra attach ssh/SERVERUSERNAME@SERVERHOSTNAME/DISPLAY
```

Comment: Hmmm... it doesn't work this way for me (tried 2 of your 3)... Will try again